# Php Class & Trait methods with same name

Tags: php, traits

I have this specific situation, my trait has a method and my class has a method, both with same name.

I need to use both methods (the one from the trait and the class) **Inside** that class which contains that same method

```
namespace Some\Namespace;
use Some\Other\Namespace\TestTrait;

class TestClass {

  use TestTrait;

  public function index()
  {
    // should call the method from the class $this->getId();
    // should also call the method from the trait $this->getId();
  }

  private function getId()
  {
    // some code
  }
}
```

And in seperate defined Trait:

```
trait TestTrait
{
    private function getId ()
    {
        // does something
    }
}
```

Please note this is not pasted code, I might have some typos :P

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use trait [Conflict Resolution](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.conflict)

```
namespace Some\Namespace;
use Some\Other\Namespace\TestTrait;

class TestClass {

  use TestTrait {
      getId as traitGetId;
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $this->getId();
    $this->traitGetId();
  }

  private function getId()
  {
    // some code
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, (sorry for late reply) I guess this will work, mind that I still will want to test this in my code, just to be 100% sure :)